# Syntax highlighting with text style instead of colors?

Tags: c++, editor, syntax-highlighting

Once upon a time I read in some book on an interesting idea of of Source code syntax visualization: they did not use colors like any (average) text editor nowadays does. Instead they tried to format the code like text in a book, thus: using different fonts, font sizes, boxes, bars, indentation etc. The code revealed its task in the way it was *formatted*, not as it was colored.

A function was basically a new section's headline in large font size (maybe underlined), the argument variables that followed were a dotted list (the example was Pascal code) - or a grey box or something. Loops might had boxes around etc. I can't remember the details, but you might get the idea.

I can not find any trace of projects that tried this again, maybe the benefit was not evident enough or the effort to implement it in some editor was too high (admittedly, it is easier to just use some different color for the same courier font).

But I am still interested whether anybody knows what happened to that idea and these projects or implementations. If you had a parse tree generator front end for a distinct programming language, say, C++, and an engine that generates this pretty printed output from a parse tree (could be done with LaTeX, probably), it might be easy to create some nicely readable code documentation just in black-white.

Edit: an example, basically taken from the TinyXml library.

The code with some common syntax highlighting using colors and a bit italic, underline would look like:
[image]

might be, just using grayscale elements like:
[image]

Comment: Hmm. I was going to say that this doesn't really fit on SO, but then I'm not really sure of any other stack exchange site that would be more suitable, except perhaps the [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) site (and even then, it doesn't really fit there, either). It isn't specifically a *programming* question; it seems to be more of an *idea* for programming *documentation*.

Comment: Also have a look at [How can a code editor effectively hint at code nesting level - without using indentation?](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/87077/how-can-a-code-editor-effectively-hint-at-code-nesting-level-without-using-ind) from the Programmers site.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Visual Studio extension called [TextHighlighterExtension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6706b602-6f10-4fd1-8e14-75840f855569). It was mainly a text colour formatter, but it could be configured with a lot of customisation to change the font type and size as well. This had a couple of defaults where 'class' and 'interface' was increased in size, for example.

I know of other extensions that are similar, if limited in scope - for example, the ["I hate regions"](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/04/16/i-hate-regions/) extension that appears to fit your question well, or the [CodeBubbles](http://www.andrewbragdon.com/codebubbles_site.asp) concept.

Comment: I was not really looking for some Visual Studio extension (but would be interesting if there were one) but rather for a backend for documenting. See my example screenshots above now.

Comment: 1) lots of people use VS, so an extension (that I linked to) does what you describe in the TinyXML screnshot. 2) the CodeBubbles IDE is totally different to VS. Check the links I put in.

Comment: 1) I do not (prefer Eclipse...) ;-)
2) CodeBubbles looks great, thanks for the hint! It is not exacly what I was looking for*), but another very innovative way to see code differently. I wish it was available for C++ as well...
*) My question was triggered because I've been reading a book the last days where the code snippets do not use any syntax highlighting at all. Awful. So I was wondering what alternative ways are there when you want to print code in a book, only using black color, in a way that the reader can grasp the syntax structure as easy as possible.